# How to RAISERROR from MSSQL into Python Pandas/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2014-express, raiserror

Anaconda 2
Pandas 0.17.1
SQLALchemy 1.0.11

Im executing an Store procedure that returns an RAISERROR that works fine inside SQL manager studio and print the messenger well.

But when I call this procedure inside Python (PyCharm 5) forcing to return the error it just say as regular success execution: "Process finished with exit code 0"

I'm doing it using conn.execute("EXEC Proc....")

So How I capture the SQL RAISERROR as a Python error or at least see the error msg on the output?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the error severity level from 11-16, then a ProgrammingError exception should be raised in python.

```
raiserror('Something bad happened!', 16, 1);
```

[More info on MSSQL error severity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)